# How I can get all data from a table in Mysql DB with Java

Tags: java, mysql, database

How can I get all data in Mysql DB with JAVA

I Have this code but he get only first row

```
if (connection != null) {
System.out.println("You made it, take control your database now!");
        Statement st = connection.createStatement();
        String sql = ("SELECT * FROM nc;");
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);

        if(rs.next()) {
        int id = rs.getInt("id");
        String str1 = rs.getString("Name");
        String str2 = rs.getString("City");
System.out.format("%s, %s, %s\n", id, str1, str2);
```

and i get in the screen : id 0 , Name Nizar, City Casablanca

so how ican get all rows in my database and thank you

Comment: use `while(rs.next())`

Answer (score 2):

If you use if the block will execute only once.If you use while the block will execute until the condition false

use `while` instead of `if`

```
while(rs.next()) {
        int id = rs.getInt("id");
        String str1 = rs.getString("Name");
        String str2 = rs.getString("City");
System.out.format("%s, %s, %s\n", id, str1, str2);  
}


rs.next()
```

will return false when all the records are completed

Comment: We don't know it. The main mistake from the OP is he didn't ilterate through the resultset.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `if` to a `while`...

```
while(rs.next()) {
    int id = rs.getInt("id");
    String str1 = rs.getString("Name");
    String str2 = rs.getString("City");
    System.out.format("%s, %s, %s\n", id, str1, str2);      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `if(rs.next())` by `while(rs.next())`.

`if(rs.next())` means "if we have one result, move to it and do the following"

`while(rs.next())` means "while we still have results, move to the next one and do the following".

Answer (score 0):

You want to change your  `if (rs.next()) {`
To be a `while(rs.next()) {`

You're only iterating through one row as it is, that will iterate through all of them.

As a best practice, don't make the contents of the while(...) loop too fancy. You want to minimize the per-row processing while iterating, so the connection doesn't stay open too long. Many people just read rows into a List, or print them out (like you're doing).